# VStudio 2019 can't open/create xamarin project after upgrade from 16.11.3 to 16.11.7

Tags: xamarin

I upgraded Vstudio 2019 from 16.11.3.to 16.11.7. After that I can't open or create a Xamarin project

Vstudio tries to open btu closes imediatly withou any error msg.

I tried with 16.11.4, 16.11.5 and 16.11.6 and get the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to repair your visual studio. For more, check:    [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) .

If the problem persist, you can perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio and reinstall again.
For more detail,please check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs.

Comment: I did that dozen of times. nothing works. I reinstalled w10 e nothing work. even with VStudio 2022 I have the dame problem. It only works with version 16.11.3. or below. Thanks

Comment: For this, you can go to [visual studio support](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/) for further sopport.

Comment: I have an open case at microsoft for 2 months. They didn't say anything yet. Thanks

Comment: It's strange that i'm the only complain for this problem.

Comment: error in ide.log.  "Xamarin.VisualStudio.UnhandledExceptionsManager Error: 0 : An unhandled error occurred. Details: Unknown property key for value                       list directories in which to look for classes!
System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown property key for value                       list directories in which to look for classes!
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.JdkInfo.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<GetJavaProperties>b__0(Object o, DataReceivedEventArgs e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\external\xamarin-android-tools\src\Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk\JdkInfo.cs:line 263

Comment: Have you tried to installed the latest visual studio 2022?

Comment: Yes I tried VS2022 and i get the same error.

Comment: You can try to manually uninstall the Android SDK (just delete the `android-sdk` folder) and then run Visual Studio installer or uninstall/reinstall the Xamarin Workflow.